# How to import JSON file using Template literal in react typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, typescript

I am getting some error while importing JSON file using Template literal in react typescript.

```
export interface IData {
  BASE_PRICE: number;
  TIER: string;
  LIST_PRICE_MIN: number;
  LIST_PRICE_MAX: number;
  DISCOUNT_PART_NUM: Discout;
}

type Discout = {
  D1RJ6LL: number;
  D1RJ8LL: number;
  D1RJALL: number;
};

const [data, setData] = useState<IData[]>([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchPrice(lang);
  }, [lang]);

 const fetchData = (lang: string) => {
    if (lang) {
      const data = import(`../locales/${lang}.json`);
      setData(data); // its giving me error like Argument of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to                         parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IData[]>
    }
  };
```

I tried this way and I am not getting any issue but also I am not able to see data in  proper way

Here is image [image: Data Format]

```
const fetchPrice = async (lang: string) => {
    if (lang) {
      const priceRangeData = import(`../locales/${lang}.json`);
      setData(await priceRangeData);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a TypeScript type and use that when AJAX returns JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320568/can-i-create-a-typescript-type-and-use-that-when-ajax-returns-json-data)

Comment: @Phoenix1355 Not quite sure because I need in react typescript

Answer (score 1):

You issue stems from `import` being an async function, which will always return a Promise with the data. Your `fetchPrice` already handles this by being an async function too, which can then await the promise as you do in `setData(await priceRangeData)`. So a solution would be to do the same for `fetchData`, like so:

```
const fetchData = async (lang: string) => {
  if (lang) {
    const data = await import(`../locales/${lang}.json`);
    setData(data);
  }
};
```

Comment: but that way json data format got change. JSON simply contain array of object. I need something similar const data = require(`../locales/${lang}.json`); which should be synchronous

Comment: @Raj You didn't specify such in your question. If the error you are receiving is something like "Promise<any is not assignable...", it means that the import method you're using is asynchronous. If you want another solution using require or alike, you need to specify such in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need make fetchData to be async function and make await before import(), because it return Promise. Don't forget make type assertion.

```
const fetchData = async (lang: string) => {
  if (lang) {
    const data = await import(`../locales/${lang}.json`);
    setData(data.default as IData[]);
  }
};
```

Comment: I am getting the data with that approach but it's not coming in the form of array of object. Already I have attached the image in que about data format while using ur approach

Comment: Oh, you use es module import, just try to make setData(data.default).